# MySQL: Get result by user name

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to get one user profile field value ( donation button code ) by username. Here are the tables

[image]

As I am not much experienced with MySQL and learning so I tried with few condition but somehow I am unable to understand how to check username with userprofile tables and get donation content.

```
SELECT ^users.userid, ^users.handle, ^userprofile.title, ^userprofile.content 
FROM ^users, ^userprofile
WHERE ^userprofile.userid=^users.handle AND title= 'donation'
```

and trying to get output using `echo $donation['content']`

But of course I know the query statement is not right but now I don't know how to write. Please help me.

**Note: ^ is nothing but database prefix**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is nested SELECT

```
SELECT `content` FROM `userprofile` WHERE `userid` = (SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `handle` = ? LIMIT 1) AND `title` = 'donation' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This query is wonderful it's directly giving content output wow thanks.. now working on outputting the content.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is perform a [table join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

(You technically are performing a join with the comma in the FROM field, however it is smart to specify a type of join in the query, if not just for readability).

There may be more results then just one, say if a user gave multiple donations. In any case, you need to fetch rows from your query result (which I can't tell if you did because you did not post enough code).  Because you're getting results from multiple tables, print the array that the row returns.

```
$result = mysql_query(/* YOUR QUERY */)
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //do stuff here later.
}
print_r($row);
```

Once you know what output the query gives, in the while loop you can access the column that you require.

I should also mention that the mysql_ functions are now depreciated, it is recommended you use the mysqli_ functions or pdo::query to access sql information.

Comment: Can you please give me some idea how to do.

Comment: There was supposed to be a link :S http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html